# Slow Disk Write Speed - Windows Server 2022 Standard

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, disk

I have an M5.XLarge server running in AWS that I recently upgraded from Server 2012 R2 to Server 2022 Standard.  It has a GP2 1200, IOPS, Unencrypted, 400 GB drive attached to it.  When I try to perform a task (e.g. SQL Backup) the Disk Read/Write speed is around 2,000,000 B/sec.

I have another identical server that I did the same upgrade and it is getting 35,000,000 B/sec.

On the slow server I've tried:

- Attaching a new EBS drive (same config) - Same read/write speed
- Disabling AV (Windows Defender) and Security Software (Sentinel)
- Ensuring VSS is disabled

No matter what action I perform (sql backup, copy file, disk performance utility) it is still slow.

On the old/original server (the new one was created by creating an AMI and launching a new instance), it performs fast.  As a result it does seem like something happened during the upgrade process (either launching the instance, creating the drive or actually upgrading windows)

Any suggestions on things I can try to help get performance back to the old state.

Comment: How long after provisioning new EC2 Instance from AMI you run backup operation?

Comment: Incremental - Hourly
Full - Daily

Comment: What does https://github.com/Alois-xx/OpenMPTest/releases give you for OpenMPTest.exe -event? On my machine this executes within 0.8s. If it is in the region of 16s you are having wrong power options (C6 states) configured for your CPU.

Answer (score 2):

> GP2 1200, IOPS, Unencrypted, 400 GB drive

Would that still be the appropriate [EBS volume type](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-volume-types.html) for your workload?
For high-performance requirements, you might consider using Provisioned IOPS SSD (io1 or io2) instead of gp2 (General Purpose SSD volumes).

Make sure also that the latest [AWS PV (Paravirtual)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/virtualization_types.html) drivers are installed on the Windows Server. Outdated drivers can cause performance issues. See "[Upgrade PV drivers on Windows instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/Upgrading_PV_drivers.html)".

And check the Windows Server for any misconfigured system settings that could impact disk performance. That includes power settings (set to High Performance), and disk write caching.

Verify that the instance is [EBS-optimized](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-optimized.html) to make sure maximum performance of your EBS volumes.

Since AWS instances have [network performance tied to instance size](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-network-bandwidth.html), make sure network limitations are not affecting EBS performance.

---

But start with measuring and monitoring:

- Use [AWS CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/WhatIsCloudWatch.html) to monitor and compare the EBS metrics (like VolumeReadBytes and VolumeWriteBytes) of both servers.

  ```bash
  aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --namespace AWS/EBS --metric-name VolumeReadBytes --dimensions Name=VolumeId,Value=vol-example --statistics Average --start-time 2023-01-01T00:00:00 --end-time 2023-01-02T00:00:00 --period 3600
  ```
- Check the Windows Event Viewer for any errors or warnings that might indicate a problem with the disk subsystem.

That way, you can measure before and after making changes to your new configuration.

Comment: Volume type (gp2) is correct.
Latest PV drivers installed
Power settings and disk write caching are configured properly.
EBS is optimized